# JSON.parse() in Swig (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-engine, swig-template

I'm trying to switch from Jade to Swig (lured by Swig's insane performance) as my Express template engine when I got stuck here — I'm sending an array of serialized JSON from Express into Swig and retrieve the data in Swig using this loop here:

```
<ul id = "list">
    {% if items %}
        {% for item in items %}
            {{ JSON.parse( item ).title }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

... but I get this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Object.Function (unknown source)
    at createTemplate (/home/vijay/node_modules/swig/index.js:72:14)
    at getTemplate (/home/vijay/node_modules/swig/index.js:109:26)
    at Object.compile (/home/vijay/node_modules/swig/index.js:153:16)
```

If I change `JSON.parse( item ).title` to `JSON.parse( item )` above, instead of errors I get this in my view:

```
function parse() { [native code] }
```

Here's a look at the `item` JSON object:

```
item { 
    id     : 2,
    title  : 'City Life ',
    author : 'Timothy J. Lindenburg',
    date   : 1337498792626,
    indent : 0         
}
```

Simply put, I want to access the individual keys and values of `item` in Swig but I can't get JSON.parse() to work. Would appreciate it if someone would point me in the right direction (I'm told Swig is based on Django templates so if you've worked with those, this should be easy).

Comment: 1. Couldn't you parse the JSON items in that array before passing it to Swig? This means something like `items = items.map(JSON.parse);`.

Comment: Of course, but I didn't want to run through the same array twice, once with the map and again with the 'for' loop, for performance reasons. Right now I'm getting 864 reqs/sec and I want that to go still higher. The second thing is that I'm not sure how to do javascript functions in Swig; there is a syntax for variables and loops but nothing's mentioned about functions so I'm hoping that solving this will show me how to do other JS functions as well.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you want to parse it. In swig it already is JSON.
So to get the title, change `{{ JSON.parse(item).title }}` to `{{ item.title }}` .