# access json data using swig-template

Tags: json, node.js, swig-template

```
{
"_id": "1",
"style": "13123",
"category": "dress",
"colors": {
    "Black": {
        "prestock": 50,
        "instock": 60,
        "inactive": 0
    },
    "Blue": {
        "prestock": 30,
        "instock": 0,
        "inactive": 0
    },
    "Red": {
        "prestock": 10,
        "instock": 60,
        "inactive": 0
    }
  }
}
```

i'm using swig-template to access 'colors' object
i need to express each color in this list-format:

Black

Blue

Red

how can i access this json?

ps. i tried other ways but no luck, 
what i have is {{style_list.colors|sort}} which gives me like this:

```
Black, Blue, Red
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON.parse() in Swig (Node.js)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671620/json-parse-in-swig-node-js)

Comment: same topic i guess, but i can't find the answer

Comment: What's your current code look like? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in JavaScript method `Object.keys`

```
<ul>
{% for color in Object.keys(colors) %}
    <li>{{ color }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: where can i find about JavaScript method documentation?

Comment: Mozilla keeps around some pretty solid documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript